# R ggplot scatterplot controlling point in legend & line color

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm having some problem with getting the correct color in legend and controlling the line color for to separate regression lines.

Output should be a scatterplot with females as red squares, and males as black dots, with the legend showing the correct color, which currently it doesn't.

Second the lines depicting the linear model should be of the same color as the squares/dots. (e.g, black for males and red for females)

This is what I got:

http://prntscr.com/6ycwc0

```
# R version 3.1.2
# ggplot2_1.0.1
library(ggplot2)
# Reproducable Example
x <- c(20, 14, 19, 25, 17, 17, 18, 16, 8, 10, 25)
Sex <- c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)
y <- c(0.116790,  0.065139,  0.362140, -2.328200, -0.348110,
       1.393600, -0.716200, -2.501600, 3.956400,  1.834400, -3.264200)
cordata <- data.frame(x,y,Sex)
cordata$Sex <- factor(cordata$Sex, labels=c("Males","Females"))

# Actual Plot:
ggplot(cordata, aes(x=x, y=y,shape=Sex)) +    
  geom_point(data= subset(cordata, cordata$Sex == "Males"),
             color="black", size = 4, show_guide = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(data= subset(cordata, cordata$Sex == "Females"),
             color="red", size = 4, show_guide = TRUE) + 

  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,16)) + 

  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL))) + 

  stat_smooth(aes(Sex = "Females"), method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
              color = "red", size = 1.5) + 
  stat_smooth(aes(Sex = "Males"), method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
              color = "black", size = 1.5)
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Sorry if this is incorrectly posted; if there is some obvious answer somewhere... But I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding two separate layers of `geom_point` and `stat_smooth` for Males and Females, you should map them to `colour`, as you already did to `shape`.

```
ggplot(cordata, aes(x=x, y=y,shape=Sex,colour=Sex)) +    
  geom_point(size=4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,15)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","red")) +
  stat_smooth(aes(group=Sex,color=Sex), method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
           size = 1.5)
```